# Facebook Login (for web) stopped working suddenly

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using [Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

As from yesterday the tool suddenly stopped working.
When clicking on fb:login-button the popup to login open, but after you enter email and password nothing happens. Until the day before yesterday all worked OK

My code

```
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          signInMem();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
        } else {
          //document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into Facebook.';
        }
    }
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.2'
        });
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { statusChangeCallback(response); });
    };
    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function signInMem() {
  FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,id,email', function(response) {

    if (document.getElementById('status')) { document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.first_name + '! Redirecting...'; }
    /* .... */      
  });
}
```

in statusChangeCallback function when console response prints

```
Object {authResponse: null, status: "unknown"}
```

what happened?

Comment: clear  browser cookies and try .

Comment: It seams like 2 cookies cause the problem. The fblo_[app_id] and fbm_[app_id]. But the visitors must deleting their cookies every time they logout in order to be able to login again via facebook?

Comment: no.keep login status in your database.when you are logging set it as true,when you log out keep it as false.so before going to login form it will check if it is true or false.but Facebook  provide those things.so read their documentation.